# Vue.js Field not set

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Vue for a date picker.

I can see the date, can click on it and select it, however when I try to retrieve the date, using the method `getDate` it is always `null`.

The code is here if anyone can help that would be great:

```
var overviewVue;

function initOverviewVue(model) {


    overviewVue = new Vue({
        el: '#overviewVue',
        data: {
            OverviewModel: model,
            repeatSchedule: [],
            startDate: ''
        },
        
       
        methods: {
            setOverviewDatePickers: function (target) {
                var $target = $(target);

                $target.daterangepicker({
                    autoUpdateInput: false,
                    locale: {
                        format: 'DD/M hh:mm',
                        cancelLabel: 'Clear'
                    },
                    timePicker24Hour: true,
                    timePicker: true,
                    singleDatePicker: true,
                    showDropdowns: true
                }, function (chosen_date) {
                    this.startDate = chosen_date.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
                    $target.val(this.startDate);
                });
            },
            getDate: function () {
                return this.startDate;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple of problems here.

It looks like the date picker you have selected is a jQuery date picker, ideally you would find a date picker that is built for the Vue ecosystem, like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker). For the sake of this question I will ignore that issue.

In your callback code where you are setting `this.startDate` the `this` is not what you think it is because you've gone into another function call.

Try changing your code to an arrow function (assuming you can support [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)) and then `this` will have the lexical scope you're looking for:

```
(chosen_date) => {
  this.startDate = chosen_date.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
  $target.val(this.startDate);
}
```

Now `this.startDate` should be what you think it is. Ideally I would recommend something built for Vue like the [recommendation above](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker) where you would not run into silly things like this so easily.

Comment: maxshuty, brilliant response thanks so much that did the trick for me.  Cheers matey.